# How to see all data If there is soo big data only one column and one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are 185.647.711 characters data in only one column and one row. So I wanna see all data. I trying to copy to text file(Ctrl+C Ctrl+P). It just geting almost half of data. İs there any way to see all data?

Comment: Is this even SQL? You want to see everything in a column but when you copy and paste you only see half? Try selecting the column in a select query

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039552/sql-server-field-getting-truncated

Comment: Maybe I can split this data using a query . But I dont know how to do.

Comment: The first issue is that you have that much data in a single tuple. That is a huge red flag that you need to revisit some design ideas. But don't use SSMS to display data like this. You can create a file directly from a query or create a quick application to do it.

Comment: Split the string in half like so: `DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX) = '123456789asdfasdf'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@string,0,LEN(@string) / 2) AS FirstHalf, SUBSTRING(@string,LEN(@string) / 2,LEN(@string)) AS SecondHalf`

Comment: *"So I wanna see all data"* Why? How are you going to consume 185M characters easily and quickly? @SeanLange is right though, don't use SSMS, create an application, or use something like `sqlcmd` to export the value to a file.

Comment: @kristech the problem with that is the max number of characters allowed to be returned in SSMS is 65,535. To capture all the characters for 185,647,711 it would require 2833 splits.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, i do realize that, which is why i didn't put it in an answer. I showed the OP how to split a string because he asked in the comment how to split a string. Anyone using this question as reference should understand the max character output.

Comment: I'd pay folding money to know how they got that much data into that field in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

I used this code but it is still running. 
" 
create table #temp(
       name nvarchar(max)
)

declare @string nvarchar(max)
set @string = (SELECT columName FROM TableName where ID = someId)

declare @i int
set @i = 50000

while @i < 185647711
begin
  insert #temp
  select SUBSTRING(@string,@i-50000,@i)
  set @i = @i + 50000
end

insert #temp
 select right(@string,185647711%50000)

select * from #temp
drop table #temp
" 
Yeah I know data is soo stupid but there is nothing to do data is data.

Comment: This is just the wrong approach entirely. This requires manipulating and evaluating this same string over and over...approximately 3713 times in fact. Use BCP or a different approach. Copying and pasting this much information is an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 0):

You can BCP OUT to a text file and open it with a text editor, either with word-wrap or without if you want to scroll forever to the right.