# How do I copy the contents of a field of datatype TEXT that's 900K+ characters long?

Tags: sql-server

I need to see a certain substring of a field named RESPONSE_STREAM whose data type is TEXT.  The DATALENGTH of RESPONSE_STREAM is 913,948 chars, which is way too long to see on my screen.  I need to retrieve the rest of the field starting from the first occurrence of 'FLEKSHER', in order to determine if there's a problem with my data.  (It's hard to be more specific than that given the nature of what I'm doing--HIPAA data, etc.)

I've tried selecting that field into a temp table and right-clicking on the field to copy it and paste it into a Word document, but the whole field doesn't get copied.

This is the SQL query that selects the field from the table it resides in to a temp table:

```
SELECT RESPONSE_STREAM INTO #tmp_foo 
FROM CMS_BATCH_RESPONSE 
WHERE BATCH_UUID ='5F61FB04-8679-48F2-B747-30C9837C85EC' AND
      RESPONSE_TYPE_CODE = 835 AND
      RESPONSE_STREAM LIKE '%FLEKSHER%'
```

Doing this told me there are 918,394 chars in the entire field:
    select DATALENGTH (RESPONSE_STREAM) from #tmp_foo

I expected the following SELECT to tell me where the string 'FLEKSHER' starts in the TEXT field--but it returned 0:

```
SELECT CHARINDEX ('FLEKSHER', RESPONSE_STREAM, 1) FROM #tmp_foo
```

Is there any way I can retrieve a substring from this very long TEXT field?

Comment: did you try using charindex without specifying the start location (708)? Are you sure the text to find is FLEKSHER?

Comment: Just a guess, but I suspect you may want to consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039552/sql-server-field-getting-truncated

Comment: Andres2142, thanks for spotting that--I took out the 708.  It was just something I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to [microsoft docs sql server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the `CHARINDEX` should work using on a variable to search for, not from a table. I would do this and see if it works:

```
DECLARE 
       @HUGESTRING VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @HUGESTRING = (SELECT RESPONSE_STREAM
                   FROM CMS_BATCH_RESPONSE
                   WHERE BATCH_UUID ='5F61FB04-8679-48F2-B747-30C9837C85EC' AND
                         RESPONSE_TYPE_CODE = 835);

SELECT CHARINDEX('FLEKSHER', @HUGESTRING);
```

Comment: Thank you, Andres2142--that did the trick!  I upvoted your response, but it's not being displayed because I haven't posted enough.